# Where are the letters ǽ and ǣ used ( U+01E3 and U+01FD)?

Tags: morphology, unicode, graphemics

I tried to find examples but while æ is widely used (Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic, Faroese, Old English at least) I can't find anything about their accented versions.

Comment: Apart from in the mentioned Germanic language, the letter æ is used (only?) in Ossetic.

Comment: The acute accent is used to mark emphatic stress in Danish (and, I believe, Norwegian, though I think they use it less than Danes tend to). The Orthography Law published by the Danish Language Council states that accents may be added to any vowel in any word, but should be used sparingly, and are best avoided altogether over å. One of the examples they give is _gǿr_ (‘barks’), so there’s no reason to think they’d have any particular objection to _ǽ_. The main reason it’s almost never used is, I think, that people don’t know how to type it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only a partial answer : æ, ǽ, ǣ and ǣ́ ***may*** be used to write a vowel present in [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English). This [vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_phonology) can be short(æ) or long(ǣ), unstressed(æ,ǣ) or stressed(ǽ,ǣ́).

Some random examples:

> æ : Beowulf.53 : Ðā wæs on búrgum Bḗow Scýldìnga,
>
> ǽ : Beowulf.3 : hū ðā ǽþelíngas éllen frémedon.
>
> ǣ : Beowul.32 : Þǣr æt hȳ́ðe stṓd hrínġedstéfna
>
> ǣ́ : Beowulf.25 : in mǣ́ġþa ġehwǣ́re mán ġeþéo͡n.

You may even find æ̀ and ǣ̀, i.e. the æ vowel with a secondary stress:

> Beowulf.69 : médoæ̀rn míċel mén ġewýrċean
>
> Beowulf.25 : lḗode ġelǣ́sten lófdǣ̀dum sceál

Comment: Good answer. Just to add: the diacritics are used only in modern editions. They were not used in actual Old English documents.